# How to develop config file in sas enterprise guide?

Tags: sas

I need to develop config file for **generating** reports and storing.

I need to create one report and develop that report using config file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does the report need to contain? How do you plan on using this config file? Do you want it to be a .sas file with macro variables that point to settings? Is it a .csv file that holds your settings and SAS reads/applies them? Please provide additional details on what you are trying to do and what you need to configure.

Comment: This is a user driven config file, there's not a defined structure or template so it's a roll your own type solution. Or do you mean a task/prompt to set parameters for the report that are triggered once EG project is opened?

Comment: Code is as follow:
%include “some external file”
%macro stats(rpt_pt =, rpt_type=);
Proc sql;
Create table &file. As select * from connection
Max(&rpt_type) as period_&flag,
From &source_db..particular table name  m
%put &sqlmsg;
Disconnect from connection;
Quit;
%mend stats;
%stats(rpt_pt = &a, rpt_type=&b);
How I can configure all the macro variables in this code??

Comment: Please update the question with the code sample you've provided. I have examined the example and you could do either of the options @StuSztukowski provided. The simplest example would be a file containing `%let` statements, e.g. `%let file=mytable;` and `%let source_db = mydb;`. Try it out and then ask another question if you get stuck on something more specific.